# My do/while loop code is not working and I can't figure out what the problem is

Tags: powershell, do-while

I am supposed to correct this code and make it display the correct output. The user enters a number between 1 and 10 any other number should prompt the user that it's an invalid number.

I tried to combine `do..while` with `do..until` and I either keep getting infinite loops or it doesn't display valid or invalid numbers.

```
[int]$UserGuess = Read-Host "pick a number between 1 and 10"

do {
    $UserGuess = Read-Host "Invalid number. Please re-enter (1 - 10)"
} while ($UserGuess -lt 1 -and $UserGuess -gt 10) {
}
do {
    Write-Host "You guessed: $UserGuess"
} until ($UserGuess -gt 1 -and $UserGuess -lt 10) {
}
```

It displays infinite loops.

Comment: Try to debug, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/components/ise/how-to-debug-scripts-in-windows-powershell-ise?view=powershell-6

Comment: Take a look at the condition of the `do..while` loop and ask yourself: what number will match that condition? Also, why is there an empty scriptblock after the conditions for both loops, and why is the `Write-Host` in a loop in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `-or` instead of `-and` and also check the first entry. The display of the result doesn't need a until-loop. And loose the empty scriptblocks.

```
[int]$UserGuess = Read-Host "pick a number between 1 and 10"

while ($UserGuess -lt 1 -or $UserGuess -gt 10)  
{
    $UserGuess = Read-Host "Invalid number. Please re-enter (1 - 10)"
} 

Write-Host "You guessed: $UserGuess"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just as mhu answered, first you need to use `-or` instead as 11 cant be bigger than 10 and smaller than 10 in the same time. Also the `do..while loop` not preferable in this case as it must give one output at least everytime which is:

> Invalid number. Please re-enter (1 - 10)

even if i have entered a correct number. If you want to use it you must use an `if statement` also to make sure it works correctly as follows:

```
[int]$UserGuess = Read-Host "pick a number between 1 and 10"

do {
    if (($UserGuess -gt 10) -or ($UserGuess -lt 1))
    {
        $UserGuess = Read-Host "Invalid number. Please re-enter (1 - 10)"
    }
} while (($UserGuess -gt 10) -or ($UserGuess -lt 1)) {
}

    Write-Host "You guessed: $UserGuess"
```

Answer (score 0):

One more example for your understanding, added some comments as well

```
$Numbers =1..10
$Userinput =read-host "Please enter number between 1 and 10 "

while(1){ ## loop for eternity

if ( $Numbers -contains $Userinput) ## if your list contains user entered number
{

write-host "You have entered right input, you guessed : $userinput"
$prompt =Read-Host "do you want to still play : Press Y for Yes ,N for No"

Switch($prompt){ ## check for second prompt

'Y' {continue}
'N' {return}
Default { "Wrong option,Press Y or N only " }

              }

}

## if user enters wrong input, he wwill be prompted again
Write-Host "You have entered wrong input,Please enter again"
$Userinput =read-host "Please enter number between 1 and 10 "

}
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly, so B'wana Beast has a better example